# How to integrate the GWT command pattern with spring

Tags: spring, gwt, command-pattern, gwt-2.4

I have a project where I am using the GWT command pattern to implement the RPC. Here how i can integrate the Spring with GWT. Without Spring I am able to achieve the RPC. But here i need to use Spring Dependency Injection for GWT server side packages.

I am unable to find suitable sample or links to implement that. 
Can anyone please provide the links and samples which has this requirement.

Without command pattern, I am able to integrate spring with GWT by referring following links

http://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/giving-gwt-a-spring-in-its-step/

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1USHYx9cB3B1s1zM4dlkzEZ759D3lEfavn_dDewvBkaA

Thanks,
Saritha

Comment: How are you implementing the command pattern - are you using a framework like gwt-dispatch?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/) then you can use the [gwt-dispatch-spring-ext](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch-spring-ext/) to make it work with spring instead of guice.  I haven't looked at these for a while - not sure to what extent they are being maintained - please do check before deciding to use these.

Comment: ok, then you can try out the gwt-dispatch-spring-ext. If this answers your question - please accept it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work